# Fitting WPF DataGrid in a Grid control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a DataGrid control inside a Grid control in one of my WPF windows.

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <SomeControl Grid.Row="0" />
  <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
</Grid>
```

The problem is that when I add rows to the DataGrid it flows out of the containing window and its scroll bar remains inactive. How do I solve this problem and make the DataGrid's scroll bar to function correctly?

Comment: try placing it under a `ScrollViewer` control and then add the grid a `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"`

Comment: I would still like to use the native DataGrid's scrolling, since it works best with this control.

Comment: Is the Grid the root element of the Window or a child of another control?  Your code should be fine as is unless its inside another control that has infinite height (e.g. a StackPanel).

Answer (score 2):

You may try as follows

```
  <Grid>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="200" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <DataGrid   Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="54,65,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="382" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ViewCount" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
```

You need to provide some height to the DataGrid ,as you  have RowDefinition Height="*"  so the vertical Scrolbar was not active,try to give  some height to the DataGrid.
Hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem;my datagrid would flow out of my grid. I have a bunch of grids I'm using, so the app will scale to the screen size. The lower row of the main grid has three data grids. 
Path=ActualHeight will only work when you are fitting the datagrid with margins; take it out! Now with my app everything resizes with the screen, except my data input UI elements, which I don't want them to. Good luck! I hope this helps.

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border Grid.Column="0" Margin="3" >
                <DataGrid x:Name="DgDbNames" CanUserAddRows="false" Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" AlternatingRowBackground="LightGray"  ItemsSource="{Binding Source=Dbs}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="True" Margin="10"  />
            </Border>
            <Border Grid.Column="1" Margin="3" >
                <DataGrid x:Name="DgTableNames" CanUserAddRows="false" Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" AlternatingRowBackground="LightGray"  ItemsSource="{Binding Source=Tables}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="True" Margin="10"  />
            </Border>
            <Border Grid.Column="2" Margin="3" >
                <DataGrid x:Name="DgSprocNames" CanUserAddRows="false" Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" AlternatingRowBackground="LightGray"  ItemsSource="{Binding Source=Sprocs}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="True" Margin="10"  />
            </Border>
        </Grid>
```